# C getopt from cmdline with more than two options

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments, getopt

You know the getopt() function. I use it to get two options with success but I don't know how to get three options. How can I do that?

Here is how I get two of them:

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "al?:")) != -1){
        switch(c){
            case 'a' :
                hide_hidden_files = false; 

                break;
            case 'l' : 
                show_file_info = true;
                break;
            case '?' : 
                //error handling here
                return 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: By adding another option and another switch case.

Comment: I didn't know the answer is so simple. Thank you :)

Comment: Next time read [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) first.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Why not add it as an aswer, so this can get "closed"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an option named `?` when you use `getopt(3)`. The letter `?` is used by `getopt(3)` to notify you of an unrecognized option letter.